# Getting more than the top 10 trending topics on Twitter

Tags: rest, http, twitter, http-headers, twitter4j

I'm trying to view the top 20 trending topics using Twitter REST Api

I'm using the following for testing (it's very helpful) although I'm originally using twitter4j

> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Anyway, for testing, I sent out the following http request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1&count=20
```

But this still returns the top trending 10 topics and not 20 as I requested. How can I return the top 20 topics instead of 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get 10 with that request.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place

Returns the top 10 trending topics for a specific WOEID, if trending information is available for it.

You could use the search API to get more results.

Comment: How can the search API be used to retrieve more than 10 trending topics? I

Comment: Use the first request to get the trends, then make a second (search) request for the additional content.

Comment: So are you suggesting caching the results from the first request, and then sending a second request and adding the newly added trends?

Comment: Yes - use the first request to get the trends, then make additional requests to get a total of 20 tweets.